# Counting algorithm for big data in R

Tags: r, algorithm, bigdata, counting

I have a big data frame with almost 1M rows (transactions) and 2600 columns (items). The values in the data set are 1's and NA's. Data type of all the values are factor. I want to add a new column to the end of the data frame which shows sum of all 1's in each row.

Here is the R code that I wrote:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dataset){
    counter<-0
    for(j in 1:ncol(dataset){
        if(!is.na(dataset[i,j])){
           counter<- counter+1
         }
     }
     dataset[i,ncol(dataset)+1]<-counter 
}
```

But it has been a very long time that it is running in R studio because the running time is O(n^2). I am wondering if there is any other way to do that or a way to improve this algorithm? (Machine has 80Gb of memory)

Comment: If your data are only 1's and NAs use a matrix (or a data.table) not a data frame. Look at `?apply`, or if that's too slow, Rcpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [eddi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18772588/168747) is the best in your case more general solution is to vectorize code (means: operate on all rows at once):

```
counter <- rep(0, nrow(dataset))
for(j in 1:ncol(dataset)) {
     counter <- counter + !is.na(dataset[[j]])
}
dataset$no_of_1s <- counter
```

One note: in your code in line:

```
dataset[i,ncol(dataset)+1]<-counter
```

you create new column for each row (cause for each step there is one more column), so final `data.frame` would have 1M rows and 1M colums (so it won't fit your memory).

---

Another option is to use `Reduce`

```
dataset$no_of_1s <- Reduce(function(a,b) a+!is.na(b), dataset, init=integer(nrow(dataset)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a matrix (of numbers, not factors), as @joran suggested, would be better for this, and simply do:

```
rowSums(your_matrix, na.rm = T)
```